# Fullcalendar not showing events from the database in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show events from the database on to the **calendar** but I'm getting the

> `alert('failed')` call every time.

Please, anyone, help me solve this issue. I'm stuck here.

**here is my script code:**

```
$.ajax({
  url:'events',
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    alert('Hello');
    $.each(data, function(index, val){
        events.push({
          title: val.name,
          start_date: val.start_date,
          end_date: val.end_date,
          start_time: val.start_time,
          end_time: val.end_time,
          location:val.location,
          description: val.description,
          timezone:val.timezone,
          alldDay: val.isFullDay
        });
    })
    GenerateCalendar(events);
  },
  error : function(error){
    alert('Failed');
  }
});

function GenerateCalendar(events){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    contentHeight: 400,
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    timeFormat:'h(:mm)a',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventLimit: true,
    eventColor: '#378006',
    events: events
  });

}
```

**Controller Function:**

```
public function getEvents()
{
  $events = Event::all();
  return response()->json(['data'=> $events])->getData();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you log your `function(error)`'s `error` parameter and see the message? something like `console.log(error);`.

Comment: where should I place this console.log method?

Comment: inside your `function(error)`, once you have added, try to open browser console (F12) then refresh the page. at least we will get the error message to check what was the issue.

Comment: it might also be useful to open the Network tab of your browser tools, refresh your page and look for the call to `/events`. Then look at the response - the status code will be shown immediately, and then if you click on that ajax call and go to the Response tab, it will show the actual data which came back from the server - perhaps there is an error. If you're still not sure what to do once you've looked for those pieces of information, then please paste them here so we can help you interpret them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your event has the attributes 
`start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time`
i have not seen anything about it in the fullcalendar [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object). 
as far as i know, fullcalendar expects the events to have an attribute called `start` which is required and an optional called `end`

From the fullCalendar documentation:

> start  -  The date/time an event begins. **Required**. A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this will become a real Moment object.

If you want to use a JSON feed to get the events there is no need to make your own ajax call. you can use the [eventSource property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) and fullCalendar will handle the fetching for you

Comment: this is all true but it wouldn't cause an AJAX error, which is what's being reported

Comment: yes, John, you are right but is there any way I can add custom fields of my own like the ones above so that I can save and retrieve them from the database?

Comment: @SohaIbAhmEd yes you can add as many custom fields you want. fullCalendar will not remove them. But the field `start` is required. So even if your ajax request would not fail. the calendar would still not display any events since they don't have the start property that the calendar needs

Comment: can you specify the exact place where I can add them ?

Comment: you can add the custom fields anywhere inside your event object. just make sure the event also has the required fields